# Append to list in boost build/b2/bjam

Tags: list, append, bjam, boost-build, b2

I would like to know how one can append items to a list in boost build/b2/bjam.

I am sure this must be easy but the search engines do not provide a result. Also Ctrl+F in [the documentation](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#jam.language.variables) does not help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator to use is `+=` [as in GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Appending.html).

Example:

```
MYLIST = a b ;
MYLIST += c ;
echo $(MYLIST) ;
```

Shows: `a b c`

And to concatenate lists:

```
MYLIST = a b c ;
OTHERLIST = dd ee ;
MYLIST += $(OTHERLIST) ;
echo $(MYLIST) ;
import sequence ;
echo length: [ sequence.length $(MYLIST) ] ;
```

Shows:
`a b c dd ee length: 5`

More information can be found in the [Variables section of the documentation](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#jam.language.variables).